# Displaying Items Polymorphically in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm trying to read from a text file and then output to a text file but I keep getting a `InputMismatchException` error. There might be a problem with my input so can someone see where I went wrong? Thanks!

This is the file that I'm pulling from:

```
S100
Sully
Ross
111-11-1111
8 15 1979
900.00

H205
Joe
Aggie
222-22-2222
3 6 1993
15.25
40

C102
Rev
Elee
333-33-3333
11 22 1985
20000
.065

B115
Johnny
Football
444-44-4444
06 28 1965
12000
.05
400

P206
Miss
Bizbee
555-55-5555
11 06 1977
1.25
1000
X
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class PayrollSystemTest 

{


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    File inputFile = new File ("EmployeePayrollInfo.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (inputFile);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Payroll.txt");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    double currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    double birthMonth;
    Employee arrayOfEmployees[] = new Employee[5];
    int count = 0;

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String ID = input.nextLine();

        if(ID.startsWith("S")){

            String first = input.nextLine();
            String last = input.nextLine();
            String ssn = input.nextLine(); //how to hide these
            //Date birth = new Date(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
            int month = input.nextInt();
            int date = input.nextInt();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            double salary = input.nextInt();
            SalariedEmployee salaryEmployee = new SalariedEmployee(ID, first, last, ssn, month, date, year, salary);
            arrayOfEmployees[count++]= salaryEmployee;
        }
        if(ID.startsWith("H")){

            String first = input.nextLine();
            String last = input.nextLine();
            String ssn = input.nextLine(); //how to hide these
            //Date birth = new Date(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
            int month = input.nextInt();
            int date = input.nextInt();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            double hours = input.nextInt();
            double wages = input.nextInt();
            HourlyEmployee HourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(ID, first, last, ssn, month, date, year, hours, wages);
            arrayOfEmployees[count++]= HourlyEmployee;
        }
        if(ID.startsWith("C")){

            String first = input.nextLine();
            String last = input.nextLine();
            String ssn = input.nextLine();
            //Date birth = new Date(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
            int month = input.nextInt();
            int date = input.nextInt();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            double sales = input.nextInt();
            double rate = input.nextInt();
            CommissionEmployee CommissionEmployee = new CommissionEmployee(ID, first, last, ssn, month, date, year, sales, rate);
            arrayOfEmployees[count++]= CommissionEmployee;
        }
        if(ID.startsWith("B")){

            String first = input.nextLine();
            String last = input.nextLine();
            String ssn = input.nextLine();
            //Date birth = new Date(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
            int month = input.nextInt();
            int date = input.nextInt();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            double sales = input.nextInt();
            double rate = input.nextInt();
            double salary = input.nextInt();
            BasePlusCommissionEmployee BasePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(ID, first, last, ssn, month, date, year, sales, rate, salary);
            arrayOfEmployees[count++]= BasePlusCommissionEmployee;
        }
        if(ID.startsWith("P")){

            String first = input.nextLine();
            String last = input.nextLine();
            String ssn = input.nextLine();
            //Date birth = new Date(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
            int month = input.nextInt();
            int date = input.nextInt();
            int year = input.nextInt();
            double wages = input.nextInt();
            double pieces = input.nextInt();
            PieceWorker PieceWorker = new PieceWorker(ID, first, last, ssn, month, date, year, wages, pieces);
            arrayOfEmployees[count++]= PieceWorker;

        }
    }
        for (Employee currentEmployee : arrayOfEmployees)
        {
            writer.println( currentEmployee );
            if(currentMonth == currentEmployee.getMonth())
            {
                writer.println("earned" + currentEmployee.earnings() + 100 );
            }else{
                writer.println("earned" + currentEmployee.earnings());
            }



            writer.println("earned" + currentEmployee.earnings());
        }



        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfEmployees.length; j++)
        {   
            writer.println("Employee is a" + arrayOfEmployees[j].getClass().getName());
        }
        writer.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Show us your stacktraceback

Comment: at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at PayrollSystemTest.main(PayrollSystemTest.java:33)

Comment: How the title is related to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check is there any contents to read before executing every `nextLine()`. That is the problem. You are using `nextLine()` which reads line by line not word by word. Use `String.split()`

```
String record = input.nextLine();

String currentRecord[] = record.split(" ");

// currentRecord[0] -> ID
// currentRecord[1] -> first
// currentRecord[2] -> second
// currentRecord[3] -> ssn
// Integer.parseInt(currentRecord[4]) -> month
//      .
//      .
//      .
```

Answer (score 0):

You must always handle the errors in your code, for instance here you just assume the input is always in the format that you want, but some times it is not, for instance you want to read 7 lines if your input starts with S but it just have 5 lines. There are multiple solution on your problem, but the thing that I thing is important is you understand importance of checking the input.